# JavaFX TableView change column sorting behavior (start with DESC instead of ASC)

Tags: sorting, javafx, tableview

I'd like to change the sorting behavior of a TableView so the initial sort is descending, followed by ascending, then back to an unsorted state. The TableColumnHeader class seems to control the sorting order transitions:

```
private void sortColumn(final boolean addColumn) {
    ...
            // the column is already being sorted, and it's the only column.
            // We therefore move through the 2nd or 3rd states:
            //   1st click: sort ascending
            //   2nd click: sort descending
            //   3rd click: natural sorting (sorting is switched off)

    ...
}
```

I don't see a way to change the order directly via the API. Anyone have any ideas on how I might implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Or if your column contains a **LocalDateTime** or some other **non string** value...

```
fxColPublishedDate.setComparator(fxColPublishedDate.getComparator().reversed());
propertyTable.getSortOrder().add(fxColPublishedDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

I accomplished this by reversing the comparator as previously suggested:

```
column.setComparator(column.getComparator().reversed());
```

Then hiding the sort arrow:

```
column.setSortNode(new Group());
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8, you can just set the comparator for your column to be the reverse of the usual comparator. For example:

```
TableColumn<MyDataType, String> col = ... ;
col.setComparator(Collator.getInstance().reversed());
```

Comment: I considered this approach, but rejected it because the table header sorting direction icon would not match how the data is being sorted.

Comment: This feature request exists!  "Add SortType-based "pattern" to TableColumn": https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-31253